# How to flat shade low-poly terrain in Unity

Tags: unity, terrain, low-poly

for 2 weeks i have been stuck trying to make procedual low poly terrain generation where each triangle in the terrain has its own color (flat shading). my terrain is just made up of a 2d array of vertices that get linked up into triangles. the problem is since some triangles share vertices the vertex color(what I am using to color my terrain) is being interpolated and the terrain looks smooth instead of flat. This makes a smooth transition from one triangle into the next, instead of a sharp one. So long story short I cant flat shade triangles or get non-interpolated normals unless I duplicate my vertices and so that each triangle has its own 3 same vertices for no interpolation which is which is very problematic.

I really dont want to make each triangle have its own 3 vertices because i think it takes up 6 times the space and speed, also i dont want to use a geometry shader because apperantly some mobile devices dont support it. It would be nice if there is a way to assign per face data so each traingle has its unique color, is that possible? Is there any way to use the color data i have without interpolating or some how maybe calculate the color in the shader??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using [the `nointerpolation` attribute discussed here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-flat-shading.410943/)?